# What tools does Blender provide for cloth modeling / simulation / animation?

Tags: modeling, animation, sculpting, cloth-simulation

I´m a real beginner on Blender but I really want to learn how to model 3D clothes after I saw some works like Catty Tay´s: https://www.instagram.com/p/BPaa-NTD6Gj/

Is Blender capable of doing such things?
What are the tools that I should use?

Any help is welcome! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. That's definetly possible to do something like that. Here's for example something I did long ago for Monorender: https://www.instagram.com/p/BsyNdcgFT3u, and I'm really not an expert in the field. Also, if you are more into stills than animations, there as been lot of improvements recently on cloth scupting. It's blender a GOOD software for that? It's opinion based. For a beginner, absolutely yes. I think your question is interesting, and I'll make some changes to your post if you allow me to.

Comment: wow! the animation is amazing! you did all of it only on blender?

Comment: Yes, and trust me, it's not difficoult. The picture you provided is probably using an animated model (you can find them online for free). You just have to put a robe on and run a simulation with the right parameter.

Comment: I edited the question: remember to not ask many questions in a single thread. For resources, tutorials, addon look here, it's all listed in those sites. :https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: A good starting point with B 2.9 can be this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg, but if you are new to the world of 3D, you should take some basic courses before going into animation and simulations.